# How to find the angle between vectors $a$ and $b$?

Tags: vectors

Given that $a$, $b$ are two none zero vectors which satisfied $(a-2b) \bot a$ and $(b-2a)\bot b$.

Then how to find the angle between $a$ and $b$?

I know that the dot product of two perpendicular vectors is zero. I tried to let $a=\binom{x_1}{y_1}$, $b=\binom{x_2}{y_2}$, and found that $a^2=b^2$, but I don't think it works in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing your solution, the dot product gives $\mathbf a^2-2\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b=0$. Therefore,
$$|\mathbf a|^2=2|\mathbf a||\mathbf b|\cos\left<\mathbf a,\mathbf b\right>.$$Since they're non-zero vectors, so $|\mathbf a|=|\mathbf b|\ne0$. Then the equation simplifies to
$$\cos\left<\mathbf a,\mathbf b\right>=\frac12.$$
Since $\left<\mathbf a,\mathbf b\right>\in[0,\pi)$, we can solve out the angle between $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ is $\dfrac\pi3$.

Comment: As a reminder, vectors should be written in bold (which you can typeset with ```\mathbf{}``` in $\LaTeX$) or with an arrow above it (which you can typeset with ```\vec{}``` or ```\overrightarrow``` in $\LaTeX$).

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got $|a|=|b|$, we have
$$a\cdot (a-2b)=a^{2}-2|a||b|\cos\theta=a^2-2a^2\cos\theta=0$$
then we have $\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}, \theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$

By the way, you don't actually need to assume the coordinates of $a,b$ to get $|a|=|b|.$

$$(a-2b)\cdot a=a^2-2a\cdot b=b^2-2a\cdot b=(b-2a)\cdot b$$

Then we get $a^2=b^2$.

Comment: "$\cdot$" means the inner product. $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\theta$